# How to select parent object and order by child's properties

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

Disclaimer: our DB is legacy and not exactly ideal. I'm trying to solve a JPA mapping problem to deal with the non-ideal DB which is beyond my work's scope to fix. Please no DB-design comments...

I have to do 2 things. I have to fetch a parent and its children, given a match on one of the child's attributes and I have to order the returned objects by the child's attribute.

I'm wondering if I can use a 'fetch join' to do this instead of a regular join.

The classes/mappings basically look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "profiles")
public class Profile  {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "profile", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    // @Where(clause = "deleted is null or deleted = 'N'")     (1)
    private List<Account> accounts;

    <...snip...>
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "accounts")
public class Account {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "profile_id", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = false)
    private Profile profile;

    private String name;

    <...snip...>
}
```

Basically the SQL I want is something like:

```
select p.*, a.*
from profiles p, accounts a
where a.profile_id = p.id and lower(a.name) like '%some_search_text%'
order by lower(a.name);
```

The problem is building a JPA query like:

```
String searchText = "%foobar%";

CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Profile> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Profile.class);
Root<Profile> profile = criteriaQuery.from(Profile.class);
Join<Profile, Account> profileAccountJoin = profile.join(Profile_.accounts);

criteriaQuery.where(
    criteriaBuilder.like(
        criteriaBuilder.lower(profileAccountJoin.get(column).as(String.class)), searchText);

criteriaQuery.orderBy(profileAccountJoin.get(Account_.name)); // ??? this maybe works

TypedQuery<Profile> query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);

List<Profile> results = query.getResultList();
```

I'll get a list of profiles whose children match. But later when converting to DTO and doing a profile.getAccounts() I'll get all the accounts the match on the profile_id, not filtered by name.

How can this behavior, specifically the example SQL query above be achieved in JPA?

If I could or should do this using a 'fetch join' how would I go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've added the `hibernate` tag, I wonder if you are happy to use a Hibernate-specific annotation, `Filter`. You might be able to define a filter on `Account` that you apply in `Profile` to filter the accounts associated a profile. This might be how you could do it:
In Account:

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.FilterDef;
import org.hibernate.annotations.ParamDef;

@Entity
@FilterDef(name = "myFilter", parameters = @ParamDef(name = "nameParameter", type = "string"))
@Table(name = "accounts")
public class Account {
...
```

And then in Profile:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "profile", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Filter(name = "myFilter", condition = ":nameParameter = name")
private List<Account> accounts;

public List<Account> getAccounts() {
    return accounts;
}
```

Finally, you need to enable the filter for your session:

```
    Session session = ...;
    session.enableFilter("myFilter").setParameter("nameParameter", "Geordi La Forge");
    Profile profile = ...;
    List<Account> geordiAccounts=profile.getAccounts();
```

That's my guess at how to do this. Perhaps it will inspire somebody to improve on it. There's documentation on filters at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-filters

Comment: Thanks. That should work. Yes, I don't realistically see us changing our JPA implementation.